# Loop Pandas DataFrame in window sizes, with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
price = [
    26810., 27524., 27728., 25739., 25221., 25767., 24367., 25056.,
    23899., 24164., 24981., 26953., 26953., 27632., 27089., 26153.,
    25846., 27628., 30096., 31153., 31153.
]

lower = [
    18012.32540124, 18930.80563138, 19349.47300484, 17600.62752257,
    17315.25044609, 18098.73169538, 16919.43582196, 17812.46170156,
    16859.50155408, 17327.29696869, 18347.99667756, 20478.26786004,
    20656.18820516, 21494.88201214, 21116.26237045, 20359.80486595,
    20228.98000157, 22085.23300384, 24515.87438892, 25390.78562257,
    25390.78562257
]

upper = [
    35607.67459876, 36117.19436862, 36106.52699516, 33877.37247743,
    33126.74955391, 33435.26830462, 31814.56417804, 32299.53829844,
    30938.49844592, 31000.70303131, 31614.00332244, 33427.73213996,
    33249.81179484, 33769.11798786, 33061.73762955, 31946.19513405,
    31463.01999843, 33170.76699616, 35676.12561108, 36915.21437743,
    36915.21437743
]

y = [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'price': price, 
    'lower': lower, 
    'upper': upper, 
    'y': y})

df
```

---

```
    price   lower           upper           y
0   26810.0 18012.325401    35607.674599    1.0
1   27524.0 18930.805631    36117.194369    1.0
2   27728.0 19349.473005    36106.526995    1.0
3   25739.0 17600.627523    33877.372477    0.0
4   25221.0 17315.250446    33126.749554    0.0
5   25767.0 18098.731695    33435.268305    0.0
6   24367.0 16919.435822    31814.564178    1.0
7   25056.0 17812.461702    32299.538298    1.0
8   23899.0 16859.501554    30938.498446    1.0
9   32164.0 17327.296969    31000.703031    0.0
10  24981.0 18347.996678    31614.003322    0.0
11  26953.0 20478.267860    33427.732140    0.0
12  26953.0 20656.188205    33249.811795    1.0
13  27632.0 21494.882012    33769.117988    0.0
14  27089.0 21116.262370    33061.737630    0.0
15  26153.0 20359.804866    31946.195134    1.0
16  25846.0 20228.980002    31463.019998    1.0
17  27628.0 22085.233004    33170.766996    0.0
18  30096.0 24515.874389    35676.125611    1.0
19  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0
20  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0
21  16313.0 20228.980002    36915.214377    0.0
```

I want to be able to loop through the DataFrame rows in windows of a specified size i.e. `window_size`and copy the 'y' value forward through this window in a new column, 'y_new' until either:

1. We reach the end of the window. In which case, we then consider the next row and loop in over the next `window_size` rows
2. The `price` column exceeds either `lower` or `upper` row values at the start of the window - in which case, we stop the loop and start again at the succeeding row.

For example:

**window_size == 5:**

**index == 0:**

- `y` == '1' # Long
- `upper` == 35,607
- `lower` == 18,012

**We loop until index == 5:**

- `y_new` at index 0 to 5 == '1' because `price` did not exceed `upper` or `lower`.

**Then, we start at index position == 6:**

- `y` == '1' # Long
- `upper` == 35,607
- `lower` == 18,012

Index == 6 to index == 9:

- `y_new` == 1

**At Index == 9,** we stop, as `price` at index 9 is > `upper` (at index 6).

We then start again: index == 10.

At index = 20, we break as our index is out of bounds.

**Desired Output**

```
df
    price   lower           upper           y    y_new
0   26810.0 18012.325401    35607.674599    1.0  1.0
1   27524.0 18930.805631    36117.194369    1.0  1.0
2   27728.0 19349.473005    36106.526995    1.0  1.0
3   25739.0 17600.627523    33877.372477    0.0  1.0
4   25221.0 17315.250446    33126.749554    0.0  1.0
5   25767.0 18098.731695    33435.268305    0.0  1.0
6   24367.0 16919.435822    31814.564178    1.0  1.0
7   25056.0 17812.461702    32299.538298    1.0  1.0
8   23899.0 16859.501554    30938.498446    1.0  1.0
9   32164.0 17327.296969    31000.703031    0.0  0.0
10  24981.0 18347.996678    31614.003322    0.0  0.0
11  26953.0 20478.267860    33427.732140    0.0  0.0
12  26953.0 20656.188205    33249.811795    1.0  0.0
13  27632.0 21494.882012    33769.117988    0.0  0.0
14  27089.0 21116.262370    33061.737630    0.0  0.0
15  26153.0 20359.804866    31946.195134    1.0  1.0
16  25846.0 20228.980002    31463.019998    1.0  1.0
17  27628.0 22085.233004    33170.766996    0.0  1.0
18  30096.0 24515.874389    35676.125611    1.0  1.0
19  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0  1.0
20  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0  0.0
21  16313.0 20228.980002    36915.214377    0.0  0.0
```

Hopefully, this is clear.

Intuitively, this feels like something that cannot be accomplished with `df.iterrows()` and I would need to use a standard loop with `break`/ `continue`. I am unsure, however, how to implement the break and restart loop at the next index.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: why there are no `y_new = 1.0` between row 10 an 14? I would have expected at least a 1 at row 12 @cmp

Comment: Because at index == 9, the price column at i == 9 exceeded the `upper` from the start of the new window (which occurred at index == 6) i .e. price at i == 9 is 32164.0, which is greater than `upper` at index == 6 (31814). Therefore, we have started again at index == 10, where `y` == 0. Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: fine with row 9, not fine with row 10-14, why don't you put ones in there as long as lower<price<upper?

Comment: Because I want `y_new` to copy forward the value at `y` from where we reevaluate. Therefore as we have reevaluated at 9, we carry forward the value of `y` until either the window ends, or the condition as your correctly pointed out above is met.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you are trying to achieve, so given your input data for 'price', 'lower', 'upper', and 'y' which I note defines a slightly different dataframe than what you show in your example.  the resulting df is shown below:
df:

```
    price   lower           upper           y
0   26810.0 18012.325401    35607.674599    1.0
1   27524.0 18930.805631    36117.194369    1.0
2   27728.0 19349.473005    36106.526995    1.0
3   25739.0 17600.627523    33877.372477    0.0
4   25221.0 17315.250446    33126.749554    0.0
5   25767.0 18098.731695    33435.268305    0.0
6   24367.0 16919.435822    31814.564178    1.0
7   25056.0 17812.461702    32299.538298    1.0
8   23899.0 16859.501554    30938.498446    1.0
9   24164.0 17327.296969    31000.703031    0.0
10  24981.0 18347.996678    31614.003322    0.0
11  26953.0 20478.267860    33427.732140    0.0
12  26953.0 20656.188205    33249.811795    1.0
13  27632.0 21494.882012    33769.117988    0.0
14  27089.0 21116.262370    33061.737630    0.0
15  26153.0 20359.804866    31946.195134    1.0
16  25846.0 20228.980002    31463.019998    1.0
17  27628.0 22085.233004    33170.766996    0.0
18  30096.0 24515.874389    35676.125611    1.0
19  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0
20  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0
21  16313.0 20228.980002    36915.214377    0.0
```

I think to implement your logic correctly, you can do what you want using the following:

```
def addColumn(dfx:pd.DataFrame, winsze:int=5) -> list:
    lower = 0
    upper = 0
    indx = 0
    val = 0
    rslt = []
    cols = list(dfx.columns)
    reset = True
    wincnt = winsze
    while indx < dfx.shape[0]:
        if reset or wincnt == 0:
            reset = False
            lower = dfx.iat[indx, cols.index('lower')]
            upper = dfx.iat[indx, cols.index('upper')]
            val = dfx.iat[indx, cols.index('y')]
            wincnt = winsze
            rslt.append(val)
            indx += 1
        else:
            if (dfx.iat[indx, cols.index('price')] >= lower and
               dfx.iat[indx, cols.index('price')] <= upper):
                    rslt.append(val)
                    indx += 1
                    wincnt -= 1
            else:
                reset = True
    return rslt
```

then assign new column using:
`df['new_y'] = addColumn(df, 5)`
which yields:

```
    price   lower           upper           y   new_y
0   26810.0 18012.325401    35607.674599    1.0 1.0
1   27524.0 18930.805631    36117.194369    1.0 1.0
2   27728.0 19349.473005    36106.526995    1.0 1.0
3   25739.0 17600.627523    33877.372477    0.0 1.0
4   25221.0 17315.250446    33126.749554    0.0 1.0
5   25767.0 18098.731695    33435.268305    0.0 1.0
6   24367.0 16919.435822    31814.564178    1.0 1.0
7   25056.0 17812.461702    32299.538298    1.0 1.0
8   23899.0 16859.501554    30938.498446    1.0 1.0
9   24164.0 17327.296969    31000.703031    0.0 1.0
10  24981.0 18347.996678    31614.003322    0.0 1.0
11  26953.0 20478.267860    33427.732140    0.0 1.0
12  26953.0 20656.188205    33249.811795    1.0 1.0
13  27632.0 21494.882012    33769.117988    0.0 1.0
14  27089.0 21116.262370    33061.737630    0.0 1.0
15  26153.0 20359.804866    31946.195134    1.0 1.0
16  25846.0 20228.980002    31463.019998    1.0 1.0
17  27628.0 22085.233004    33170.766996    0.0 1.0
18  30096.0 24515.874389    35676.125611    1.0 1.0
19  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0 1.0
20  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0 1.0
21  16313.0 20228.980002    36915.214377    0.0 0.0
```

Comment: I don't think your output matches OP's

Comment: @sammywemmy, No my output dosen't match OP's but as I pointed out, that is because the data provided for creating the dataframe df doesn't match the dataframe he shows as an example.  Thus, I believe the logic is correct but the final result differs from his output

Comment: @itprorh66 Thank you for your answer - I actually wrote a function myself which I think answers the question, using a standard loop. Yours is certainly close to the logic I have except the condition in the `else` block: I want to copy the col, `y` forward for every iteration unless `price` >= `upper` or <= `lower`, in which case we take the next observation for `y` and continue. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have written to achieve the above. It is not the most elegant, or efficient by any stretch, it assumes structure and column order, and the condition to check where the iteration is near the end of the DataFrame is somewhat suboptimal, so please feel free to edit and improve:

```
def _assign_no_overlap(df: pd.DataFrame, window: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    assert all(np.isin(['price', 'lower', 'upper', 'y'], df.columns)), \
    f"df missing cols: {df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['price', 'lower', 'upper', 'y'])]}"
    df = df.copy()
    df = df.dropna()
    df['y_non_overlap'] = -1
    # Get non-overlapping labels
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        # Initial conditions
        if i == 0:
            initial_y = df.iloc[i, 3]
            initial_upper = df.iloc[i, 2]
            initial_lower = df.iloc[i, 1]
        # Rolling conditions
        price = df.iloc[i, 0]
        df.iloc[i, 4] = initial_y # y_new == y
        if (len(df)-i) < window:
            break
        # Price exceeds upper/lower, reevaluate y
        if (price >= initial_upper) or (price <= initial_lower):
            price = df.iloc[i, 0]
            initial_y = df.iloc[i, 3]
            initial_upper = df.iloc[i, 2]
            initial_lower = df.iloc[i, 1]
            # assign y_new to latest pred
            df.iloc[i, 4] = initial_y  # assign y_new to latest pred
            continue
        # At end of window - take new prediction
        elif i % window == 0:
            price = df.iloc[i, 0]
            initial_y = df.iloc[i, 3]
            initial_upper = df.iloc[i, 2]
            initial_lower = df.iloc[i, 1]
            df.iloc[i, 4] = initial_y # assign y_new to latest pred
            continue

    return df

df_n = _assign_no_overlap(df, 5)

    price   lower           upper           y    y_non_overlap
0   26810.0 18012.325401    35607.674599    1.0  1.0
1   27524.0 18930.805631    36117.194369    1.0  1.0
2   27728.0 19349.473005    36106.526995    1.0  1.0
3   25739.0 17600.627523    33877.372477    0.0  1.0
4   25221.0 17315.250446    33126.749554    0.0  1.0
5   25767.0 18098.731695    33435.268305    0.0  0.0
6   24367.0 16919.435822    31814.564178    1.0  0.0
7   25056.0 17812.461702    32299.538298    1.0  0.0
8   23899.0 16859.501554    30938.498446    1.0  0.0
9   32164.0 17327.296969    31000.703031    0.0  0.0
10  24981.0 18347.996678    31614.003322    0.0  0.0
11  26953.0 20478.267860    33427.732140    0.0  0.0
12  26953.0 20656.188205    33249.811795    1.0  0.0
13  27632.0 21494.882012    33769.117988    0.0  0.0
14  27089.0 21116.262370    33061.737630    0.0  0.0
15  26153.0 20359.804866    31946.195134    1.0  1.0
16  25846.0 20228.980002    31463.019998    1.0  1.0
17  27628.0 22085.233004    33170.766996    0.0  1.0
18  30096.0 24515.874389    35676.125611    1.0  1.0
19  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0  -1.0
20  31153.0 25390.785623    36915.214377    0.0  -1.0
21  16313.0 20228.980002    36915.214377    0.0  -1.0
```